Constructing spaces of $1$-dimensional foliations of $\mathbb P^n$
I want to construct spaces whose points are foliations of $\mathbb P^n$ of dimension $1$ and bounded degree. Recall that a foliation of $\mathbb P^n$ of degree $\le r$ is generated by a nonzero section of the twisted tangent sheaf
$$\mathcal E_r := \mathcal T_{\mathbb P^n}(r-1) \cong \dfrac {\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(r)^{\oplus (n+1)}} {\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(r-1)},$$
where the inclusion $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(r-1) \hookrightarrow \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(r)^{\oplus (n+1)}$ is given by multiplication times $\rho = (x_0, \dots, x_n)$. Two sections $\alpha, \beta$ of $\mathcal E_r$ generate the same foliation if and only if there exist sections $f, g$ of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(s)$ such that $f\alpha = g\beta$.
The above motivates the following definition. Let $A = \mathbb C[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ be the homogeneous coordinate ring of $\mathbb P^n$. Define the following equivalence relation on each graded piece of $M = A^{n+1}$:
$$\alpha \sim \beta \iff \text{there exist $f, g, h \in A$ such that $f\alpha + g\beta + h\rho = 0.$}$$
Let $X_r = U_r / \sim$, where $U_r \subset M_r$ is the complement of the equivalence class of zero. Notice that, for $r \le s$, we have a canonical inclusion $X_r \hookrightarrow X_s$ given by $[\alpha] \mapsto [f\alpha]$, where $f$ is any homogeneous polynomial of degree $s-r$. Is there any natural way to endow each $X_r$ with the structure of an algebraic variety (or scheme or whatever), such that the inclusions $X_r \hookrightarrow X_s$ are morphisms?
